# Should I use "in good standing" or "of good standing"?

Tags: grammar

I am typing a Certification for an individual. Should I use *in good standing in the community* or *of good standing in the community*? In what context should I use *in* and *of*?

Comment: Depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

"in good standing"

This refers to a person or company. It doesn't refer outside of itself, i.e. someone is not in good standing relative to something else, except perhaps the law or a set of rules.

"of good standing in"

This person stands well in comparison to their community and is well-regarded in their community.

You need version 2.

---

You may like to click on the links at the bottom of this Google Ngram to compare usage.
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+good+standing%2Cof+good+standing&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20good%20standing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20good%20standing%3B%2Cc0

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thanks. That Ngram Viewer is new to me.

Comment: I disagree that there is the difference you assign to them. (Note that you left out the second *in* in the first version.) Can you point to any evidence of that distinction? As far as I'm concerned, they mean exactly the same thing (it wouldn't make sense to say one but not the other). The only difference is that one is more common than the other.